# GWTP: Troubles to display a CellTable

Tags: celltable, gwtp

Hi I'm new to GWT and so, to GWTP too.

I try to play with CellTables and I decided to begin by building a simple one following GWT documentation at developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#celltable
I adapted few things to match GWTP MVP design.

First, I created my Celltable on my View.ui.xml file:

```
xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client">
<g:HTMLPanel>
     <c:CellTable pageSize='15' ui:field='cellTable' />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Then, I created a class Contact:

```
public class Contact {
    private final String address;
    private final String name;

    public Contact(String name, String address) {
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

in my View.java file:

```
@UiField(provided=true) CellTable<Contact> cellTable = new CellTable<Contact>();

public CellTable<Contact> getCellTable() {
     return cellTable;
}
```

Finally in my Presenter.java file:

```
public interface MyView extends View {
   CellTable<Contact> getCellTable();
}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();

    // Create name column.
    TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
          @Override
          public String getValue(Contact contact) {
            return contact.getName();
          }
        };

    // Create address column.
   TextColumn<Contact> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
          @Override
          public String getValue(Contact contact) {
            return contact.getAddress();
          }
        };

    // Add the columns.
    getView().getCellTable().addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
    getView().getCellTable().addColumn(addressColumn, "Address");

    // Set the total row count. 
    getView().getCellTable().setRowCount(CONTACTS.size(), true);

    // Push the data into the widget.
    getView().getCellTable().setRowData(0, CONTACTS);
}
```

Everything seems good to me but there is no CellTable displayed when I try this code...And I get no errors...

Thanks in advance for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not use/have DataProvider registered for your CellTable. GWT CellWidgets are based on DataProvider/DIsplay pattern. So CellTable is just a Display for your DataProvider. One DataProvider could have multiple displays.

You do not need to write:

```
// Set the total row count. 
getView().getCellTable().setRowCount(CONTACTS.size(), true);

// Push the data into the widget.
getView().getCellTable().setRowData(0, CONTACTS);
```

You need to register your CellTable as a Display for your DataProvider (eg ListDataProvider) and than call refresh method when you update DataProvider with new data.